# 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command ONLY in specific vscode project

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, cmd

Node is added as an envrionment variable and works with CMD, but once VS Code is opened and a node command is ran, i.e "yarn" "node" "npm" it will display the message 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command. Restarting VS Code does not fix it.

[System Properties - Path settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WMsu.jpg)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I managed to fix it...

Restarting VS Code wasn't property terminating the terminal session, as hinted by this message: [Terminal Session Restored](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXlcG.png)

You must click the Kill Terminal button (highlighted) and then restart VS Code and node will start working again.

Comment: Best on making a change of __system__ environment variable `Path` is restarting Windows to make sure that really all processes make use of the modified `Path` variable. Please take a look on my very detailed answer on [What is the reason for "X is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41461002/3074564)